# HighChart Data Table Custom Export

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a `line-chart` using `HighCharts.js` which should be showing the data in tabular format too. But data has to be grouped instead of exact input for the graph.

Normal export shows the exact input data. 
like Jan - 0, Feb - 2 etc..

But I want to show a table where it suggest how many months are there where data is 0, 1, 2 ,3.

```
+------+-------+
| Data | Count |
+------+-------+
| 0    | 2     |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 2     |
+------+-------+
| 2    | 4     |
+------+-------+
| 3    | 1     |
+------+-------+
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Data Table Example'
    },
    
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        spacingBottom: 30
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2],
    }],
    exporting: {
        showTable: true
    }

});
```

```css
.chart-outer {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
#container {    
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    min-width: 380px;
}
.highcharts-data-table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background: white;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even), .highcharts-data-table thead tr {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #eff;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    border-bottom: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div class="chart-outer">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <!-- data table is inserted here -->
</div>
```

**Update**: we are using Json Object as input for our chart and the table has be be exported as well with the highchart export option.

Comment: Based on this Highcharts demo, it's the table that powers the chart, not the other way around (see https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/). . It *should* be possible to do what you're asking, but could you share how your data are provided to the chart? Is it directly inserted, JSON array, etc.?

Comment: We are inserting it via JSON Array

Comment: OK, great. One other question: did you want to the table to be included when users export the chart? The Highcharts demo has the table as a separate HTML element, and wouldn't be in the export. I'm just making sure based on how you phrased your question.

Comment: Yes, Export is also required.